# FeignClient: Serialize RequestParam to JSON

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, feign

I have a spring boot application in which I am trying to use `Feign` to communicate with a remote service. My `@FeignClient` is defined as follows:

```
@FeignClient(name="TEST_SERVICE", url="URL")
@Component
public interface SomeServiceClient
{
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/someService",
        consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json"
    )
    SomeServiceResult getServiceResult(
        @RequestParam(value = "mode") String mode,
        @RequestParam(value = "payload") SomeServicePayload payload
    );
}
```

I would like the `payload` object of type `SomeServicePayload` to be serialized into JSON. I expected this to happen automatically, but it does not. Instead, `payload` is serialized to its fully qualified class name.

Do I need to set a custom encoder/decoder combination for this client? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`@FeignClient` under the hood used `toString()` method for bulding request string. The easiest way to create proper request is to override `toString()` method manually:

```
class SomeServicePayload{
    String payload;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"payload\":\"" + payload + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Or for complex objects by using ObjectMapper:

```
public class SomeServicePayload{

    private String payload;

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            //...
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? Does Feign relies on `toString()` instead on the Spring's `ObjectMapper`? I can't see any benefit. How can this behavior be switched to use ObjectMapper? For example, using object mapper allows to serialize including metadata properties such as type info which enables polymorphism on serialized objects. And I need to achieve this behavior for Feign.